# How Can I Disable Files Watcher In VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm getting this error: "File changes watcher stopped unexpectedly. A reload of the window may enable the watcher again unless the workspace cannot be watched for file changes."

I don't use or want Files Watcher. How do I turn it off completely?